# Set Python27 Google AppEngine default encoding for entire app

Tags: google-app-engine, encoding, python-2.7

I would like to set the default encoding to utf-8 for my python27 appengine site. The default is ascii.

There was a similar question answered http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5923. It says to not use sys.reload after setting the default encoding or you will lose a request.

How can i set utf-8 encoding for my entire python appengine site, without having to encode strings specifically like the link suggests above?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start your python 27 code (every Python file) with:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

But sometimes you have to use .encode('ascii') if you use HMAC or you have to set http headers.
Or you can use:

```
self.response.headers[str('Content-Type')] = str(content_type)
```

or

```
 self.response.headers[b'Content-Type'] = str(content_type)
```

And make sure:

- all your HTML files use UTF-8
- your editor uses UTF-8 by default

Comment: Do I have to do the main.py file? Or to every single python file that has request handlers in them? Thanks!