# When setting default encoding to UTF-8 in Google App Engine, do I have to set it in all python files?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-unicode

I got this code in this answer: [Set Python27 Google AppEngine default encoding for entire app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370867/set-python27-google-appengine-default-encoding-for-entire-app/13371411#13371411)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Do I have to do this just in main.py (file with request handlers) or to every single python file that I create?

Comment: Some good insights also in here: https://pythonhosted.org/kitchen/unicode-frustrations.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, like the `from __future__ import` line the `# coding` line only ever applies to the *file it is placed in*.

Python uses it when compiling the source file to bytecode, and you are free to use different encodings for different source files should you so wish.